# Vuetify v2.3.14 v-calendar getVisibleEvents function return empty array

Tags: function, calendar, vuetify.js

How do you get the visible events in vuetify with the calendar component in type month? I use the getVisibleEvents function and it returns an empty array. I am using vuetify version 2.3.14

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this may help

```
                <v-date-picker
                  color="custm_theme_6"
                  v-model="date"
                  :max="new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)"
                ></v-date-picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

With @change event call to eventos_visibles

```
eventos_visibles({ start, end }) 
  let elementos = 0
  const start_date = `${start.date} 00:00:00`
  const end_date = `${end.date} 23:59:59`

  this.calendario.forEach((element) => {
    console.log('element: ' + JSON.stringify(element))
    ...
  })
},
```